# How do i know when IPSEC Phase 2 Has completed with Openswan?

Tags: vpn, ipsec

When I bring up a connection using openswan I get the following output but I don't see any ESP traffic through ports 50, 500 or 4500.

```
# ipsec auto --up globacom-vpn
104 "globacom-vpn" #44: STATE_MAIN_I1: initiate
003 "globacom-vpn" #44: received Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-03] method set to=108
106 "globacom-vpn" #44: STATE_MAIN_I2: sent MI2, expecting MR2
003 "globacom-vpn" #44: received Vendor ID payload [Cisco-Unity]
003 "globacom-vpn" #44: received Vendor ID payload [Dead Peer Detection]
003 "globacom-vpn" #44: ignoring unknown Vendor ID payload [607de1f3f9ce64c53c6ae5e6d2ef9f6a]
003 "globacom-vpn" #44: received Vendor ID payload [XAUTH]
003 "globacom-vpn" #44: NAT-Traversal: Result using draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02/03: no NAT detected
108 "globacom-vpn" #44: STATE_MAIN_I3: sent MI3, expecting MR3
004 "globacom-vpn" #44: STATE_MAIN_I4: ISAKMP SA established {auth=OAKLEY_PRESHARED_KEY cipher=oakley_3des_cbc_192 prf=oakley_sha group=modp1024}
117 "globacom-vpn" #45: STATE_QUICK_I1: initiate
003 "globacom-vpn" #45: ignoring informational payload, type IPSEC_RESPONDER_LIFETIME msgid=38752b6f
004 "globacom-vpn" #45: STATE_QUICK_I2: sent QI2, IPsec SA established tunnel mode {ESP=>0x4ca8129b <0xfc055e21 xfrm=3DES_0-HMAC_SHA1 NATOA=none NATD=none DPD=enabled}
```

Comment: I believe once you've established the IPSec SA the tunnel is successful. Are you sending traffic through the tunnel?

Comment: Now that's the problem. How do I send traffic through the tunnel? I have tried to ping, telnet, netcat etc... the traffic refuses to use the tunnel

Comment: If you have a tun or tap interface.  `ping -I tun0 <ip to ping>`

Comment: What is a tun or tap ?

Comment: A virtual interface that is created to handle traffic for your IPSec tunnel.  `ifconfig` should show you if you have one or not.

Comment: # ping -I 172.16.255.1 10.100.108.51
PING 10.100.108.51 (10.100.108.51) from 172.16.255.1 : 56(84) bytes of data.

104.131.13.155 > 10.100.108.51: ICMP echo request, id 25151, seq 91, length 64
    104.131.13.155 > 10.100.108.51: ICMP echo request, id 25151, seq 92, length 64

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35602/discussion-between-rora-and-oladipo-olasemo).

Comment: Yes. Please lets do that.